# Alarm manager for background services

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager, android-alarms, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have implemented the alarm manager to wake up the background services every 15 mins periodically. It is working fine, but since the inclusion of DOZE mode Android 6.0, the seems like behaving strange and not waking up in every 15 mins. Although, I am using the method alarm.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(), but still not working in Idle state

here is my method for implementing Alarm Manager

```
 private void serviceRunningBackground()
{
    final Intent restartIntent = new Intent(this, service.class);
    restartIntent.putExtra("ALARM_RESTART_SERVICE_DIED", true);
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
   Handler restartServiceHandler;
    restartServiceHandler = new Handler() {
         @Override
         public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
             pintent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, restartIntent, 0);
             if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
                 Log.d(TAG, " Marshmellow "+ TIMER_START_TIME);
                 alarmMgr.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 900000, pintent);                  
             } else {
                 alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 900000, pintent);
             }
             sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, TIMER_START_TIME);
         }
     };
    restartServiceHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 0);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated..thanks

Comment: Are you testing on which version as of now?

Comment: Android 6.0 preview on Nexus 5,

Comment: Use `System.currentTimeMillis()+900000` and it will fire the alarm after 15mins. You will need to write such code again inside your initial method of `service.java` so it will set alarm for next 15mins.

Comment: I will check, just a question it is strange as they did not provide method such as setRepeating()...correct me if I am wrong

Comment: They are trying to improve battery life and even `setRepeating` is no more firing alarm on exact time since API 19 or above. checkout Note section on this `http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int, long, long, android.app.PendingIntent)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public class PollReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver{
    static final String PERIOD = "period";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
         startWakefulService(context,new Intent(context,MyService.class));
         long period = intent.getLongExtra(PERIOD,-1);
         if(period>0){
         scheduleExactAlarm(context,(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE),period)
         }
    }


    static void scheduleExactAlarm(Context context,AlarmManager alarms, long period){
    Intent i = new Intent(context,PollReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,i,0);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1){
        alarms.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + period,pi);
    }
}
```

Ive tested scheduling alarms in this way in Doze and it works. They go off every 15 minutes. Check out https://commonsware.com  , thats where I found this method of scheduling a repeating alarm.