# Alarm Manager does not work in background on Android 6.0

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast, android-alarms, android-broadcastreceiver

This is my `Activity` code,

```
Long time = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+20000;//Setting alarm after 20 sec
Intent intentAlarm = new Intent("alarm");
intentAlarm.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intentAlarm.putExtra("req_code",10);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,10, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent);
```

These are all the permissions that I have in my app,

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.myapp.pack.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

This is my `BroadcastReceiver` code,

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
        context.getSharedPreferences( "mydata", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("elligible",true);
        editor.apply();

    }
```

I have registered my `BroadcastReceiver` in the manifest,

```
 <receiver android:name="com.myapp.pack.AlarmReciever" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="alarm" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

The above code successfully executes the `BroadcastReceiver` on pre-MarshMallow devices in the background ,but on a MarshMallow device ,the `BroadcastReceiver` does not get executed. Does anyone know what could be happening here? Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can try which, when used in concert, *should* be able to cut through all of the idle/standby/doze modes (irrespective of OS version).

**1.**  Use a [`WakefulBroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) instead of an ordinary `BroadcastReceiver`. Make sure you include the [`WAKE_LOCK`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WAKE_LOCK) permission to use it correctly.

**2.** Use the [`setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()`](https://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExactAndAllowWhileIdle%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) method (on API 23 & above) to schedule the `Intent` for the receiver:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19){
        setExact(...);
    }
    else{
        set(...);
    }
}
else{
    setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(...);
}
```

**References:**

**1.** [**Alarm manager for background services**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33432661/3287204).

**2.** [**A flowchart for background work, alarms, and your Android app**](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/GdNrQciPwqo).

Comment: So if I use `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` will I have to change minimum sdk version of my app to 23?

Comment: `setExact()` is available only from API 19. So you need to do that check as well in`else if` in the condition in the snippet.

Comment: setExactAndAllowWhileIdle() is not consistently giving desire output...in several devices like gionee, xiaomi, samsung and others more.....in some devices its not fire on perfect time, in others its not fire......

Comment: @himCream: Could you kindly describe your problem in more detail, preferably in a new question?

Comment: My problem is: I have following code : alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        calendar.getTimeInMillis(), sender); setting alarm every 30 min with WakefulBroadcastReceiver but in some devices some times its missing to calling the alarm and some time its calling alarm after 2-3 min by desire time.....i m confirming it by logs

Comment: What device are you using? I suggest you check it in the emulator first and confirm that it is working properly ...

Comment: Isn't doze mode supposed to ignore wake locks? Can anybody confirm if this works as intended?... Also will it allow network ops?

Comment: @Kushan: the `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` and `setAlarmClock()` methods surely cut through Doze. The `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` is an additional scaffold.

Comment: I read somewhere that even if the alarms fire... The service/ receiver won't start... This method sets your app in whitelist for ten seconds... I'm worried whether this will let my receiver or an intent service work and do network operation...

Answer (score 7):

The reason can be [Doze mode](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html) introduced in Android 6.0 Marshmallow. Use [setAlarmclock()](https://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setAlarmClock(android.app.AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) instead of `set()`. It's designed specifically for alarm clocks and may be able to cut through doze. There are a few adb commands you can use to manually put a phone into doze or app standby mode:

https://developer.android.com/preview/features/power-mgmt.html

If that isn't able to wake your app up, there's the surefire method [setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()](https://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) is designed to wake the phone from doze no matter what. Worst case scenario, you can wake your app up with this method and use the wakeup to schedule the next alarm.

**Reference:**
[How to make Alarm Manager work when Android 6.0 in Doze mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32492770/how-to-make-alarm-manager-work-when-android-6-0-in-doze-mode)

Comment: Ok i'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

In my experiment, AlarmManagerCompat + setAlarmClock is stable to wake up in doze mode. I use xiaomi device which use MIUI.

```
AlarmManagerCompat.setAlarmClock(alarmManager, time, showIntent, pendingIntent)
```

Please vote up if this benefit for you, cheers!