# Service not running when app is closed

Tags: android, android-service, android-alarms

I am trying to implement alarm application using AlarmManager and Service

In my Activity, i have declared the following to initiate a alarmservice

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OnAlarmManager.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(),
        234324243, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+(i * 1000), pendingIntent);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Alarm set in " + i + " seconds", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

My OnAlarmManager code looks like this

```
public class OnAlarmManager extends Service{
    private static final String TAG = "OnAlarmReceiver";

    private NotificationManager nm;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent mainActivityIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, mainActivityIntent, 0);

        //setting up notification
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("New Notification")
                .setContentText("This is a successfull app on service")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .build();
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
        nm.notify(0, notification);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Alarm has begun", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i(TAG, "Alarm has begun");
         return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

Now when i try running this, the notification is triggered at given time in device running on JellyBean even when i close the app after setting the alarm. 
But in the device running on Marshmallow, the service class is never triggered when the app is closed

Is the something i am missing here?

Comment: You may want to check this questions first
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34378707/alarm-manager-does-not-work-in-background-on-android-6-0

Comment: does not help. Notification is triggered when app is running or when it is running in background. But once i swipe the app away or close it, everything associated with it(receiver, service) is being destroyed

Answer (score 1):

Could you try foreground Services? http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

From what you say it seems like the service is running on the main thread and it gets killed together with the app.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake, try using `AlarmManager.setExact` with `IntentService`. Your code will look something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(OnAlarmManager.ACTION_TRIGGER_ALARM);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(),
        234324243, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Alarm set in " + i + " seconds", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+(i * 1000), pendingIntent);
} else {
    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+(i * 1000), pendingIntent);
}
```

And your service will look something like:

```
public class OnAlarmManager extends IntentService {
    public static final String ACTION_TRIGGER_ALARM = "com.example.myapplication.ACTION_TRIGGER_ALARM";

    private static final String TAG = "OnAlarmReceiver";

    private NotificationManager nm;

    public OnAlarmManager() {
         super("OnAlarmManager");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent mainActivityIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, mainActivityIntent, 0);

        //setting up notification
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("New Notification")
                .setContentText("This is a successfull app on service")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .build();
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
        nm.notify(0, notification);
        Log.i(TAG, "Alarm has begun");
    }
}
```

and add the action information in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<service
    android:name=".OnAlarmManager"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.myapplication.ACTION_TRIGGER_ALARM" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: While using IntentService , its asking me to add a constructor in service class. While i do it, the following constructor class is added                
 public OnAlarmManager(String name) {
        super(name);
    }                                                                                                                          Adding this part gives me a error in manifest declaration telling me that there is no default constructor in Onalarmmanager. Also the app crashes

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed it in the sample code. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Added it, just like in the questions i mentioned, the notification is triggered while running in the background , but once i close the app, everything is destroyed

Comment: Alarms should be triggered, being in foreground or background shouldn't affect its working. That's strange.

Comment: Which device are you testing it on?

Comment: Huawai G Play Mini, Marshmallow 6.0 and Xiaomi Redemy Note 2 , Lollipop

Comment: Can you try using a broadcast receiver in place of that `Service`? I'll update the answer with code for the same if you need.

Comment: Already tried it. After unsuccessful attempts with BroadcastReceiver, i moved towards service.

Comment: https://github.com/developeravsk/AlarmClock                                                            You may take a look at it. Any suggestion would be of big help

Comment: Works on my OnePlus2 like a charm. I know about the strict changes in Xiaomi Redmi Note 2 framework that saves a lot of battery by killing stuff in background, not sure about Huawei. AlarmManager should work perfectly in any case though, if that doesn't work, the phones won't be selling so good.

Answer (score -1):

Just register the service in Manifest.xml file as

```
<service android:name=".YourServiceClassName" />
```

Comment: Done that already. Without doing it, it wouldn't even run on the device running on  JellyBean

Comment: It appears to be working on JellyBean devices already, so the service declaration must be obviously present.